# How to use a rest service result as valuelist for a value picker control

Tags: rest, xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

An external Domino Server exposes application data, which I need in my application, as a Rest Service. In fact, they use a viewJsonService and I know they exposes column1 up to column8, but I have no other access to the data. The URL looks like: http:\extserver\database.nsf\restservice.xsp\extdata, where 'extdata' is the pathinfo.

I want to consume the data returned by that Rest Service as an input to the valuelist of a value picker control in my xpage. In detail, I want to use the value from column2 as the value in the value picker and the value from column5 as the label in the value picker.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: what is the data type returned by that rest service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little Java is needed. The social business toolkit has samples how to consume a Web Service. It is available on OpenNTF.

There are a few caveats you need to watch out for (not specific to XPages, but remote data in a UI) :

- the service might require authentication
- the call takes time, so your user experience
- a good caching strategy makes sense (view scope,  session scope, app scope)

Hope that helps